# How to send a non-local attachment with JavaMail

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-mail, attachment

I'm building an application using jsp's, servlets, and all that fun stuff.  Right now, I have a form that passes through all the information from the form to an html email that is sent using the JavaMail API.  It works, but I am trying to send an attachment, and the way I have it set up right now does not work...

```
<div class="section">Upload Files: <input id="fileUpload" type="file" /></div>
```

I take this input's value, pass it through to my servlet and try to send the email.  The problem is that when the file is sending, the servlet cannot locate the file because this tag gives it the path

```
C:\fakepath\file.doc
```

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: What are you using to process the file upload? @MultipartConfig or Apache Commons Fileupload? I'm not sure what you mean by 'taking the inputs value', as the form field itself will have nothing useful for you, as far as file upload goes. Could you post some of your code?

Comment: @Perception That input field is all I'm using to process the upload.  It seems to basically take the file and pass it as a field, which obviously would only work for local files, if at all. I just take the value from that input field and pass that through right now.  I'm trying to find something to upload the file and process it that way instead using Java.  Any ideas?

Comment: I see. And you want to use this to allow user to upload file from their computer, to use as attachment on email you will be sending, correct?

Comment: @Perception yes that is correct.

Comment: @Perception I figured it out. I posted it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  The fakepath was a security feature in browsers.  What happens though with tomcat is that the file is actually stored in a temp folder inside the tomcat folder.  So i just had to play with a tomcat library, commons.fileupload, and i used that to pull the data from the file, regardless of the fakepath location.

```
//Handle File Upload for the attachment
           ServletFileUpload servletFileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory());

            try{
            List fileItemsList = servletFileUpload.parseRequest(request);

            //TODO: Take datafile input from the field and pass the file name so that we can view the file name

            Iterator it = fileItemsList.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()){
              FileItem fileItem = (FileItem)it.next();
              if (fileItem.isFormField()){
                /* The file item contains a simple name-value pair of a form field */
              }
              else{ //do what you want with the file}
```

I then passed it through to my mail utility, changed the name of the file to the correct name to have the correct extension, and it worked. Of course, you have to encode the form as a multipart form, and you have to make the Mime Message multipart as well. But its fairly simple after all that.

```
    MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    textPart.setContent(body, "text/html");



    MimeBodyPart attachFilePart = new MimeBodyPart();
    FileDataSource fds = 
        new FileDataSource(file);
    attachFilePart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
    attachFilePart.setFileName(fileName);


    Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
    mp.addBodyPart(textPart);
    mp.addBodyPart(attachFilePart);
```